# Popularity Trends

Tags: sharepoint-server, popularity-trends

We are using SharePoint 2016 and I have a problem with Usage Report. The search Queries is fine and I can see all the reports without no issues.

I can also see the Usage report was working fine around early this year.

The SSA works fine.

Not sure why ImportProgress.ini update time was 13/07/2016 as I believe it should be every 5 minutes

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ImportProgress.ini file will be directly related to the job Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import, check whether the timer job is working.

Check whether the disk is full.

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Sharepoint 2013 popularity trend zero count after patch](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169215/sharepoint-2013-popularity-trend-zero-count-after-patch)

Comment: Thanks Lisa, Timer job is running every 15 minutes and the status is succeeded. there is no data under EventStore path and under RequestUsage the data is up to date. Please see the screen shot. The confusing part is I have 2 site collections, Popularity trends shows in one of them and the other one its shows 0s

Answer (score 0):

So, after spending 3 days I managed to fix the issue.
The trick was you need to make sure both **EventStore** and **RequestUsage** are both up and running.