# Site Page is not giving the details (Popularity Trends) in ShP *2013*

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, popularity-trends

I tried this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d59f55cb-dead-4325-ad9c-9e9101bfa07d/sharepoint-2016-popularity-trends-excel-report-not-showing-the-data-zero-hit-count-for-few-page?forum=SP2016

But there is no Get-SPUsageDefinition in PowerShell.

And I tried this: [Popularity Trends](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272901/popularity-trends)

But IDK how to make both EventStore and RequestUsage both up and running.

Thanks for your advice.

Greetings